# How can I use NameIdentifier Claim for trusted identity provider?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am trying to setup a custom trusted identity provider in SharePoint.

The provider issues a claim of type `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier`to uniquely identify the user.

If I use the argument `-IdentifierClaim http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier` in the command

```
$ap = New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer -Name $trustedTokenIssuerName -Description $trustedTokenIssuerName -Realm $realm -ImportTrustCertificate $cert -SignInUrl $providerUri -IdentifierClaim http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name -ClaimsMappings $map2,$map3
```

then I get  the error

```
New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer : Identifier Claim currently selected is not in the list of mapped claims.
At C:\Users\nathan.davis\Desktop\Deploy\configTrustedIdentityProvider.ps1:48 char:7
+ $ap = New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer -Name $trustedTokenIssuerName -Descriptio ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (http://schemas....ity/claims/name:String) [New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSPIdentityProvider
```

However if I try to map the `NameIdentifier` claim like so:

```
$map1 = New-SPClaimTypeMapping -IncomingClaimType "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "NameIdentifier" -SameAsIncoming

$ap = New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer -Name $trustedTokenIssuerName -Description $trustedTokenIssuerName -Realm $realm -ImportTrustCertificate $cert -SignInUrl $providerUri -IdentifierClaim $map1.InputClaimType -ClaimsMappings $map2,$map3
```

Then I get the error

```
New-SPClaimTypeMapping : The mapping is not allowed as the claim type
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier is a reserved claim type.
At C:\Users\nathan.davis\Desktop\Deploy\configTrustedIdentityProvider.ps1:42 char:9
+ $map1 = New-SPClaimTypeMapping -IncomingClaimType "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (http://schemas..../nameidentifier:String) [New-SPClaimTypeMapping], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSPClaimMapping
```

How can I get SharePoint to use the `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier` claim issued by the provider as the `IdentifierClaim`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible to directly map the nameidentifier claim as itself. However, I was able to map it to a different local claim type and get it working, e.g.

```
 $map1 = New-SPClaimTypeMapping -IncomingClaimType "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "NameIdentifier" -LocalClaimType "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn"

 $ap = New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer -Name $trustedTokenIssuerName -Description $trustedTokenIssuerName -Realm $realm -ImportTrustCertificate $cert -SignInUrl $providerUri -IdentifierClaim $map1.InputClaimType -ClaimsMappings $map1,$map2,$map3
```